# Can helpers detect new elements created by createElement()?

Tags: meteor, helper, createelement

I have a page with table. Each table row, has two links "delete", and "edit". "delete" works fine.

I would like to do this scenario:

When user clicks on row "edit" link, a small window appears with the fields of this row.
User decide to edit or not.
User may press "Save Changes", or "Cancel".
I did the option of small window with JavaScript document.createElement(), and the window appears successfully.
But I would like to add helpers for "Save Changes", and "Cancel" buttons.
I can't do this using helpers

```
Template.codesList.events({
    'submit form#newForm': function (events) {
        // some actions
        };
    },

    'click #edit': function () {
        var px     = 'px';

        // Create an Overlay
        var myOverlay = createOverlay();
        document.body.appendChild(myOverlay);

        // Create edit window display it over the Overlay
        var editWindow = createPopup(300, 400);

        // Create elements and append it to edit window
        var editForm = editWindowForm(this._id, this.name);

        editWindow.appendChild(editForm);
        document.body.appendChild(editWindow);
    },

    'click #delete': function () {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            Codes.remove({_id: this._id})
        }
    },

    'submit form#editForm': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Clicked");  // This doesn't displayed
    }
});
```

And this is the form after displaying it.

```
<form id="editForm" style="margin-right: 3em; margin-left: 3em;">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemCode" class="control-label">Code</label>
    <input id="itemCode" name="itemCode" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter code">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemName" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input id="itemName" name="itemName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name">
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-info">
</form>
```

But when I press on "Save Changes" button, no print from console.log() and the form is making the normal submit and the page reloads again.
So, what I'm missing?

By the way that's the output of the console:

```
document.querySelector('form#editForm')
<form id=​"editForm" style=​"margin-right:​ 3em;​ margin-left:​ 3em;​">​…​</form>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Define edit form as a template. Use event handlers as usual to handle save and cancel button clicks.

To render it, either just put it inside the page template with '#if sessionEditPopup' or if you must do it yourself then use UI.renderWithData [docs here](http://meteor.github.io/blaze/docs.html#ui_renderwithdata)

BTW manually modifying DOM using jquery etc is something to be avoided unless there is no other way and is not the Meteor way of doing things.

Comment: How to make the edit form see the row data that user clicked on it?

Comment: `this` inside your event handler will give your the data context for the row. You can use it as the last parameter of `UI.renderWithData` or set it as a `Session.set('editRowData', this)` to retrieve it

Comment: mmmm, thank you I got it. I was take session feature in my calculations. And you're right in that, It is not the Meteor way of doing things.
Thanks for the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Add event on click save the data into Session because Session can access globally.
And Take the data from Template.name.Healper using session,
So when u change the session value that will automatically change your page content.
Here is the link may be useful for U
http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/sessions/